# .Net performance with C# TCP Socket Server

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, sockets

I have strange performance results with my C# TCP Socket Server.

When I start it on "clean" just installed Windows (Xp, 7, 8 - never mind) it work slow. But when I run Visual Studio setup, or JetBrains dotTrace application my server begins work fast!

Running of Visual Studio Ultimate can help too...

Even in realtime. Just run one of these applications and server begins to "fly".

Sometimes server performance improve per se.

I used Process Explorer and found that in low performance case "cycles delta" of threads had value (around 8 000 000) but in high performance case it grown up to 50 000 000!

Can someone tell me what is this?

Is this some system boost?

**Update**:
Here are video of this process:

http://youtu.be/SOlbEG4u7fY
and 
http://youtu.be/HRYVyxZxxNU

I found new effect. I have boost, when Visual Studio Setup "play" animation before closeing.

Fraps have same "boost" effect.

Meyby it can be linked with video subsystem...

Comment: and what is the exact .NET version on clean vs with VS? My initial guess would be "different .NET version"

Comment: Server use .Net 4 Client Profile. Installation of Full .Net do not change anything. Perfomance changes without installation of Visual Studio. Just start setup application can help.

Comment: I think some other applications can give this effect. It looks like system boost or .net boost. I playd with Thread and Process priority - no effect.

Comment: Are you attaching the VS or Jetbrains to the process? If so, could there be some anti-virus or firewall blocking the normal process, but when running with attached (and added to excluded list) program the virus/firewall check is bypassed?

Comment: Please elaborate how are you exactly measuring performance. Other issues could be related to JIT compiling or with/without optimizing.

Comment: No. I am not attaching to process. Just Open main window. I get only Windows Brandmauer. I'v try to turn it off - no effect.

Comment: Server update about 200 devices settings after start. And I measure time of this process. I can measure reading of this settings by client else.

Comment: It's about 30 seconds in lo perfomance and 3-4 seconds in hi perfomance.